# What's the purpose of the environment variable CI set to true within a Github workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

Let's take this workflow as an example which is based on the [NodeJS starter workflow](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/master/ci/node.js.yml#L24).

```
name: continues integration workflow
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: checkout repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: setup node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '13.x'
    - run: npm test
      env:
        CI: true
```

What is the purpose of setting `CI: true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `CI` variable is there for compatibility with other CI systems. Here are the facts as I know them:

1. GitHub Actions itself, does not have any use or need for the `CI` variable.
2. Other CI systems - like Travis and CircleCI - always set `CI=1`.
3. Unlike other systems, GitHub Actions does not set `CI=true`, since it is not intended for CI only. Instead, it sets `GITHUB_ACTIONS=true`.
4. The conventional use for the `CI` variable, is so that your tests and app configuration can check for its existence, and do something differently if they need to (for example, skip certain tests on CI, or configure a different setting when on CI).

If your code and test code do not have the `CI` variable in them, then you can probably omit this setting and have the same result.

Answer (score 7):

Note that [since April 2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-04-15-github-actions-sets-the-ci-environment-variable-to-true/), you will not see anymore

```
env:
  CI: true
```

That is because `CI` is now always set to true, by default.

As noted, this will allow for a script to check if it is running within the context of a CI/CD environment.
You find the [same convention in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

> Mark that job is executed in CI environment